# Quarkus configurable Path from spring-cloud-config

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

We are currently migrating from spring-boot to quarkus.
In spring-boot, we used to have the path take the pathvariable from spring-cloud-config using expression language using this:

`@RequestMapping("${url.microservice.controller.base-path}")`

This all worked correctly.
However, now that we are migrating to Quarkus, we want to make the  path configurable as well from spring-cloud.

I have not been able to get this to work, as the java compiler expects a constant at the path.

Is there any way to get this to work which i'm missing?